# How to listen to the unselect of Listbox item in ZK Composer

Tags: zk

Currently I'm Listening in composer on the select event of the Listbox. Now I want to raise the event on unselect of the checkmark of the listbox item so as to know which item is deselected from the listbox.
Is there any Zk's functionality available for this or have to apply some custom logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is written before checking the Java Doc.
https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.2/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/SelectEvent.html

Unselecting raise a selectevent, and guess, there is even a method what gives you the unselected items.